# How to add a new locale to a Edge browser extension?

Tags: localization, internationalization, microsoft-edge-extension

My extension includes 29 locales. They are seen as such on Chrome and Firefox.

However, on Edge, even if those 29 locales are detected in the package file, only 1 language (en_US) is displayed in the developer dashboard and on the store to the users.

The "Add language" button of the store listing page for the extension is greyed out.

Is it just a bug in the platform or did i miss something to enable multi-language support ?

Edit:

I am reasonably confident that i declared the locales correctly in the manifest because:

- the Edge version of the extension is very similar to the Chrome and Firefox ones that have several million users and have run that way for 3 years
- the first screen for the extension in the Edge dashboard shows the languages detected from the package:
  [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48mw8.png)

However, the store listing only shows the American English version and the "Add language" dropdown is disabled:
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceTWJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I am not sure if you have configured it correctly, **name** and **description** in **manifest.json**. Pay attention to the "_" in the name and description. For more details, you can refer to these two articles:
[The Best Way to Localize Your Chrome Extension](https://betterprogramming.pub/the-best-way-to-localize-your-chrome-extension-a7b283fc520a)
and
[Publish in the Chrome Web Store](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/publish/#step3).

This is the result of my simple test:

[image]

If you can provide relevant screenshots, or a minimal example that can reproduce the problem, it will help to find a solution to this issue, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a couple of screenshots in the original question.

Comment: This is different from my test results. In my test, the detected languages are consistent with those listed in Store listings. I'm not sure if there are other problems in your code, can you provide a sample that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Whatever problem i could have in my package, the point is that the Edge developer interface detects correctly the languages in the package (screenshot 1) but does not allow providing those languages in the Edge extension store (screenshot 2).
Thank you for confirming it should allow all present locales. I assume this is a bug in the Microsoft Edge developer platform.

Comment: Have you read this document: [Internationalizing Your App - Name and Description](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/i18n/#name-and-description) .Will it cause the same problem? If it can work normally, then I think there may be some problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I went into this problem. The Edge store will not recognize that your extension is multilingual if the extension name and description in the manifest are not localized. You need to have something like this in `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "__MSG_ext_name__",
  "description": "__MSG_ext_description__",
```